# Rewrite $A\exp(x)+B\exp(-x)$ to obtain $A'\cosh(x)+B'\sinh(x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My prof. wrote this today:

$$ Ae^{\alpha_n x} + B e^{-\alpha_n x} + C' \cos(\alpha_n x) +D'\sin(\alpha_n x)$$
$$ =A'\cosh(\alpha_n x) + B'\sinh(\alpha_n x) + C' \cos(\alpha_n x) + D'\sin(\alpha_n x)$$

Can someone please help me to understand how he got the second line from the first line?

How does he arrive at $A'\cosh(\alpha_n x)+B'\sinh(\alpha_n x)$ from $Ae^{\alpha_n x}+Be^{-\alpha_n x}$ ?

Thank you for your effort and your time!

Comment: @E.Joseph Thanks a lot for the nice editing !

Comment: *Full answer:* use the identities $$e^{\alpha_nx}=\cosh(\alpha_nx)+\sinh(\alpha_nx)\qquad e^{-\alpha_nx}=\cosh(\alpha_nx)-\sinh(\alpha_nx)$$

Comment: @Did your approach works! In this case A' = (A+B) and B'=(A-B), right ?

Comment: Exactly. No need to solve a linear system (at the risk of solving it wrongly, as happens below).

Comment: @Did yes, your're right! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: How do you define the hyperbolic functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to it should be like this. $$Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x} = Ae^{\alpha x}+ Ae^{-\alpha x}+ (B-A)e^{-\alpha x} = 2Ash(\alpha x)+ (B-A)e^{-\alpha x}$$
But we have that $e^{-x} = ch(x)-sh(x)$. So we will have. $$Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x} = 2Ash(\alpha x) + (B-A)(ch(\alpha x)-sh(\alpha x)) = (A+B)sh(\alpha x)+ (B-A)ch(\alpha x)$$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! You are using a similar concept than the comment form @Did .

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
A'\cosh(ax)+B'\sinh(ax)=\frac{A'+B'}{2}e^{ax}+\frac{A'-B'}{2}e^{-ax}.
$$
So $\frac{A'+B'}{2}=A$ and $\frac{A'-B'}{2}=B$, giving $A'=A+B$ and $B'=A-B$.

Comment: see that your answer is wrong. just put your answer in the equilities you wrote.

Comment: @kolobokish why???

Comment: See that if $A'$ and $B'$ are as above, that you'll not get $A$. You'll get $\frac{A}{2}$.

Comment: @kolobokish Thanks. Was a quick fix.

Comment: Now that's ok.) Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to be explicit here: $\cosh \alpha_n x$ and $\sinh\alpha_n x$ are `independent` `linear` combinations of the linearly independent  vectors $\mathrm e^{\alpha_n x}$ and  $\mathrm e^{-\alpha_n x}$, hence they span the same subspace.